# PythonでPandasを使わずにファイル内の複数のCSVファイルを列方向に結合する方法を知りたい

Tags: python

ファイル内に格納された複数のCSVファイルについてPandasモジュールを使わずに
列方向に結合して1つのCSVファイルとして出力したい．
[image: CSVファイルの中身はこのような2列のデータから構成されています．][image: ファイル内にはこのように複数のCSVファイルが格納されています]

Comment: 「Pandasモジュールを使わずに」の理由を教えていただけますか？また、時刻をキーにマージしたいわけではなく、単純に横に追加していきたいのですね？

Comment: 結果としてどのような形式のCSVファイルが欲しいのか、何故pandasを使わない/使えないのか、その問題について貴方自身が何か着手して試したことは有るのか、試したことがあるのならそれで何かエラーが発生したり結果が望むものでは無かった等の状況が有ればソースコードと共に追記してみてください。今の質問内容だとやりたい事や欲しい結果の説明も中途半端だし丸投げ状態ですね。こちらのヘルプ記事を参考にブラッシュアップしてください。[良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: CSV構造も不明です。図からはヘッダーかどうか不明な行がありよく分かりません。可能ならテキストで示してください。 / pandasの件は別コメントにもあるけど, それによっては NumPyの選択肢がありかどうかも変わるでしょう

Comment: あとは色々な条件がどうなっているかの説明も必要です。各CSVファイルの行数(つまりデータの総数)が違う・`time [s]`の列の値が0.01間隔ではなかったり飛んでいたり重複していたりする・2列目の値が無くて空白だったりする、といった場合が存在するのか否か、そうした場合が存在する時はどう対処するのかの情報などです。

Answer (score 1):

コメントで御指摘のとおり条件が曖昧なので御参考になりますが，「入力ファイルの文字は ASCII のみ，入力ファイルの行数が異なる場合は最も少ないファイルに揃えて結合（余り行は切り捨て），出力ファイルの改行コードは環境依存（Win: CRLF, macOS/Linux: LF）」で記述例を示します。

```
files = ['Run01.csv', 'Run02.csv', 'Run03.csv']
result_file = 'Run.csv'

n_file = len(files)
data = []
for i in range(n_file):
    with open(files[i], 'r') as f:
        data.append(f.read().splitlines())

n_line = min([len(data[i]) for i in range(n_file)])

result = []
for j in range(n_line):
    result.append(','.join([data[i][j] for i in range(n_file)]) + '\n')

with open(result_file, 'w') as f:
    f.writelines(result)
```

なお， （[RFC 4180](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180) に準拠して）macOS/Linux 環境でも改行コードを CRLF にするには最後の `open()` に `newline='\r\n'` を追加してください。

Answer (score 0):

おそらく質問の雰囲気的に以下のような形式のCSVファイルにしたいのではないでしょうか？
`time [s]`の列は左端に1つだけ存在して、各CSVファイルの2列目がその右側に順々に並んで増えていく形だと思われます。

| time [s] | dm2@hrpipeinput1_2_Run1 | dm2@hrpipeinput1_2_Run2 | dm2@hrpipeinput1_2_Run3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0.751883 | 0.851883 | 0.951883 |
| 0.01 | 0.127555 | 0.227555 | 0.327555 |
| 0.02 | 0.127819 | 0.227819 | 0.327819 |
| 0.03 | 0.127843 | 0.227843 | 0.327843 |
| 0.04 | 0.127845 | 0.227845 | 0.327845 |

その場合は以下のようなスクリプトで変換できるでしょう。

```
import csv
import glob
import os

f_dir = './'
f_name = 'Run??.csv' #### 元のCSVファイル群のワイルドカード表現
out_f_name = 'Result.csv' #### 結果出力ファイル名：上記と衝突しない形式

#### 該当フォルダのCSVファイルを列挙して読み込み、
#### time [s]の列をキー、2列目を値とする辞書のリストとして作成
#### 1つのCSVファイルを1つの辞書とし、各ファイルをリストの1行として扱う
#### 全てのCSVファイルは同じ行数で同じtime [s]が揃っていると仮定
dictlist = []
for fpath in sorted(glob.glob(os.path.join(f_dir, f_name))):
    dictlist.append(dict(list(csv.reader(open(fpath, newline='')))))

#### データ数が不揃いだとかtime [s]の列の値が飛んだり重複したり等があるなら
#### この段階で調整して行・桁の数を揃えたデータを作成する処理を挿入する

#### 辞書のリストをヘッダー付きの値の2次元リストに変換
valuelist = [list(dictlist[0].keys())] #### 辞書のキーをヘッダー行として抽出
valuelist.extend([list(d.values()) for d in dictlist]) #### 値を2次元リスト化

#### 2次元リストの行と列を転換する
result = list(map(list, zip(*valuelist)))

#### 結果をCSVファイルとして書き出し
with open(out_f_name, 'w', newline='') as f:
   writer = csv.writer(f)
   writer.writerows(result)
```

---

あるいは @Delft View さん回答のように元のCSVファイルのデータをすべて活かして結合するなら、こちらのスクリプトになります。

```
import csv
import glob
import os

f_dir = './'
f_name = 'Run??.csv' #### 元のCSVファイル群のワイルドカード表現
out_f_name = 'Result.csv' #### 結果出力ファイル名：上記と衝突しない形式

#### 該当フォルダのCSVファイルを列挙して読み込み、
#### すべてのCSVファイルのデータを活かして、各列を行データとして追記していく
worklist = []
for fpath in sorted(glob.glob(os.path.join(f_dir, f_name))):
    worklist.extend(list(map(list, zip(*list(csv.reader(open(fpath, newline='')))))))

#### データ数の不揃い等があるなら
#### この段階で調整して行・桁の数を揃えたデータを作成する処理を挿入する
#### 以下は一番大きい行数のファイルに合わせる形の処理
max_count = max([len(i) for i in worklist])
valuelist = []
for row in worklist:
    count = max_count - len(row) #### データ数が最大より小さいか判定用
    if count:
        row += [None for x in range(count)] #### 小さいなら残りにはNoneを追加
    valuelist.append(row)

#### 2次元リストの行と列を転換する
result = list(map(list, zip(*valuelist)))

#### 結果をCSVファイルとして書き出し
with open(out_f_name, 'w', newline='') as f:
   writer = csv.writer(f)
   writer.writerows(result)
```